# Do lingerie bags protect delicates from damage in washing machines?

Tags: consumer-products, clothing

Mesh lingerie bags are widely sold to protect lingerie and other delicate fabrics from damage in the washing machine. They are also known as wash bags. An example of such a product [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001GNPTT2).

> Protects delicate bras, panties, slips, hosiery and sleep-wear from snags, tangles and tears

I've been using them with my lingerie for the last two years or so, and I haven't noticed any protective value in using the bags. My lingerie seems to get damaged at the same rate as before using the bags and sometimes bras snag on the bag itself. I was wondering if there is any evidence **at all** that they do what they are advertised to do, or are just a gimmick device.

Comment: Hello Sam, I'm not an expert, but, as far as I know, washing machine using centrifugal force and rotating waterfalls are very dangerous for lingerie. FWIW, it would be better to use ULTRASONIC CLEANING for that fabrics.

Comment: ULTRASONIC CLEANING.

Comment: It may depend on the design of the machine. I used to have one which regularly tore holes in small garments due to the design of the door seals. Mesh bags helped prevent problems. I now have a different make of machine which doesn't cause damage.

Comment: I'm very very much aware that it isn't good to machine wash lingerie, but it isn't all that important to me. Using anything but the washer isn't very convenient for me.

Comment: I can't add a source, as it comes from a time I was employed at whirlpool, but the reason given for lingerie bags was to stop small items from disappearing or receiving damage from the seams/seals in the washer/dryer. They don't protect the garment from damage from the washing action.

Comment: I asked my wife to stop using those lingerie bags for the bloody bra-catching problem. I do most of the washing and it was a nightmare getting stuff out of those bags.

Comment: @MarkHenderson isn't that an argument for the bags - would you rather rip a 100 yen net or a 5,000 yen shirt?

Comment: We use these bags to protect the washing machine from the bra's metallic parts (if they have them), not the other way round. We've started using them after losing a washing machine to a bra wire.